# Is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{p\leqslant x}p^{1/x}$ finite?

Tags: number-theory, limits

I suspect $$\prod_{p \leqslant x}p^{1/(p-1)}\sim\sqrt[x-1]{x!}$$ and I was able to show that it is true if the finiteness of the above limit is true: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{\pi(x)\log(x)/(x-1)}\prod_{p\leqslant x}p^{1/(x-1)}\tag{$\star$}$$  Is $(\star)$ finite or infinite? Alternatively, is there some interesting literature on that product?

---

Of course, by the prime number theorem $\left(e^{\pi(x)\log(x)/x}\right)^{1/(1-x^{-1})}\longrightarrow1,$ so it further reduces to whether$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{p\leqslant x}p^{1/x}\lt\infty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you can be even more precise. Prime number theorem gives
$$\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\log p}{p-1}=\log x-\gamma+o(1),$$
where $\gamma$ is an Euler constant. Exponentiating yields 
$$\prod_{p\le x}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}\sim e^{-\gamma}x.$$

Comment: How is it a consequence of the prime number theorem? Can you add a reference, please?

Comment: You can look it up in Mongomery and Vaughan book on Multiplicative number theory or Tenenbaum Probabilistic Number theory. The proof goes through deriving the asymptotic formula for $\sum\frac{log p}{p}$ first. Unfortunately, I do not have those books right now, but will be able to add precise sections later.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $\log\left(\prod_{p\leqslant x}p\right)$ grows like $x$, this would imply $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{p\leqslant x}p^{1/x}=e.$$ Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any reference.

---

[Paul Erdős proved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate#Lemma_4%3a_An_upper_bound_on_the_primorial) $\prod_{p\leqslant x}p\lt4^x$, so the limit is indeed finite and less than four. This suffices to show that $$\prod_{p\leqslant x}p^{1/(p-1)}\sim (x!)^{1/(x-1)}$$